# What is VPN on demand, and how do I get it to work with iOS?

Tags: ios, vpn

I know what a VPN is, and I've done [a little reading](http://www.0x8847.net/2010/07/iphone-os-vpn-on-demand/) about how to set up VPN on demand. However, I'm confused.

Is VPN on demand essentially a certificate instead of a password prompt on each connect? Do apps need to take care of this specifically, or does iOS handle it whenever it sees that an app wants VPN on demand? What is VPN on demand?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT:** This answer is outdated. Here are some newer links that may help you if you are trying to set up VPN On Demand:

- https://support.apple.com/apple-configurator
- https://support.apple.com/guide/mdm/vpn-overview-mdm2d2adb35d/1/web/1
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/vpn
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/personal_vpn/vpn_on_demand_rules

---

Yes, it does involve authentication by certificate. From [this article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_VPN_Server_Configuration_for_iPhone_OS/Introduction/Introduction.html) from Apple:

> iOS supports VPN On Demand for networks that use certificated-based authentication. You specify which domains require a VPN connection by using a configuration profile.

The VPN connection is made whenever the device tries to connect to certain domains. Specific apps don't need to do anything; as soon as they try to access such a server the VPN connection is initiated.

Visit [this support page](http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-ipcu/#appbec2d1af) for information about how to use the Configuration Utility to create a configuration profile that sets up VPN On Demand.

Comment: In general, though, this feature need not be tied to certificate-based authentication schemes. Your company might serve *crazycoolcats.corp* and it may be really important that employees using iOS devices be able to reach that service. You can use on-demand vpn to configure iOS to use your local DNS servers when resolving **.corp* domains.

Comment: FYI support page links is broken.

Comment: Yes...page links are broken @jtbandes

Comment: Anyone found solution for this? Need help for VPN - Connection On Demand

Comment: How about https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment-reference-ios/intro-to-vpn-on-demand-iord4804b742/1/web/1 ?

Comment: Thank You @jtbandes do you have demo for this...triggering VPN on demand in iPhone using Swift4